# "in plural form" or "in the plural form"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Is the use of definite article necessary in the below sentence?

> How would you say the word *man* in (**the**) plural form.

Comment: You've got a typo, it's "plural"

Comment: You would say: What is the plural of the word man? If you want to be simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can say either "in the plural form" or "in plural form".

However "in the plural form" is more idiomatic and common.

Answer (score 0):

> A countable noun has two **forms**, singular or plural.

Above example shows how **form** in cases like **singular form** or **plural form** is *countable*.

Similarly, **form** in your example is used as singular-countable;

> How would you say the word man in (the) plural **form**.

A *singular-countable noun* is **never** used without a article or any other determiner. [for more](https://cegepenglish.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202713955-Generalizations-Non-Specific-References-When-to-Use-a-the-or-plural-s-)

Therefore, you cannot omit **the** in your sentence and should include it or replace with any other determiner or a pronoun as follows;

> 1. How would you say the word man in **the** plural form.
> 2. How would you say the word man in **its** plural form.